# Por qué me sale este error Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-validate

Tengo un problema bastante curioso, sucede que estoy utilizando JQuery Validate y cuando mando llamar el método `valid` me marca el siguiente error ***Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #Nueva_Contrasena_(Opcional)***, el código HTML del campo es el siguiente:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.1/dist/jquery.validate.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<form id="form" method="post">
    <label for="Nueva_Contrasena_(Opcional)">Nueva Contraseña (Opcional)</label>
    <input id="Nueva_Contrasena_(Opcional)" name="Nueva_Contrasena_(Opcional)" class="f-control float-left" autocomplete="new-password" style="border-right: none; width: 80%;" type="password" minlength="5" maxlength="12">
    <span class="btn btn-light float-left crud-toggle-password">
        <i class="icon-eye"></i>
    </span>
    <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var form = document.getElementById("form")
    form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault()

        try {
            if ($(this).valid() && $(this).valid()) {
                // CORRECTO
            }
        }
        catch (error) {
            alert(error)
        }    
    }
    
    var jqvForm = $(form).validate({
        lang: "es"
    })
</script>
```

Sé que usar el valor *Nueva_Contrasena_(Opcional)* causa el problema, sin embargo funciona sí agrego el atributo **required**, inclusive puedo reemplazarlo, por ejemplo *Nueva_Contrasena* y desde el inspector regresar el valor nuevamente a *Nueva_Contrasena_(Opcional)* y funciona. Me interesa saber por qué afecta el (Opcional) o bien saber si es lo que está provocando el error y por qué falla en algunos casos.

Comment: Saludos. Tanto `id` como en `name` debes revisar la forma correcta de estos; puede ser que el **(Opcional)** lo quiera evaluar de alguna forma como una expresión y esto sea lo que genera el error.

Comment: Si por evaluar como expresión te refieres a los filter selectors de JQuery: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-filter-selectors/, entonces tienes toda la razón, resolvi el problema, pero no acababa  de entender el porque, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los filter selectors de JQuery: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-filter-selectors son **expresiones** como dijo RobertoLeOr de los selectores que sirven para filtrar mejor los elementos, por ejemplo *eq()* `$("div:eq(0)")` los parentensis sirven para llamar estos filtros, así que si tenemos atributos (id y name) con parentesis en los valores puede que en algunos casos sean tomados como filter selectors, usar diagonales invertidas es una buena opción, aunque la mejor solución es no usar parentesis en nuestros id y name si no es necesario.